# What is the difference between these three Oracle datatypes?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, types

- `char`
- `varchar`
- `varchar2`

I understand that `varchar2(10)` will allocate space dynamically upto 10 bytes. `char(10)` will allocate 10 bytes at the beginning and fill it with junk if the actual datalength is less.

If this is correct, what does `varchar(10)` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all covered quite comprehensively in the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i3253).

Answer (score 3):

I think this explains it directly
http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types

Comment: Becareful with that FAQ. There is much misinformation contained within. False claims include, but are not limited to: `CHAR` is faster than `VARCHAR`, the max size of `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` ar different. `VARCHAR` follows the ANSI standard. (It doesn't, Oracle's `VARCHAR` can not hold a zero length string. Zero length strings are equiv to `NULL` in Oracle.)

Comment: @Shannon, the FAQ itself is correct - it does say `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` are identical - but your warning does apply to the comments that people have added.